# how to display multiple meta_key / meta_values per SQL query in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

It turns out that I want to list through sql all the posts of a new instance of wbdb, but I only get the meta_value of just a meta_key of the 4 or 5 that I have, then I show my attempt.

```
function seconddb() {
    global $post;

$seconddb = new wpdb('aa', 'vv', 'Jcc', 'ddd');
$rows = $seconddb->get_results("SELECT meta_value FROM K1nG_posts INNER JOIN K1nG_postmeta ON ( K1nG_posts.ID = K1nG_postmeta.post_id ) 
 WHERE K1nG_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (K1nG_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR K1nG_posts.post_status = 'private')  and ( meta_key = 'imagenm' or meta_key = 'urlm')
 LIMIT 1");
foreach ($rows as $obj) :
    echo var_dump($obj->meta_value);



endforeach;
}
add_action('init', 'seconddb');
```

With the previous code I only get a meta_value, not the 2 indicated ...

Comment: Remove `limit 1` ?  Also SQL tables/resultsets are defined to be orderless by ANSI/ISO SQL standards, meaning using `limit 1` to get the "first" matching record is pretty meaningless in SQL without using `ORDER BY`

Comment: if that does not help, see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)